# Ordenar un array de objetos de acuerdo a un clave

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, javascript-objeto

Buen dia,

tengo el siguiente array de objetos en jQuery, el cual traigo de Ajax

```
array = [{"proveedor":"juan","producto":"198","color":"BLANCO"},
    {"proveedor":"andres","producto":"256","color":"AMARILLO"},
    {"proveedor":"juan","producto":"244","color":"AMARILLO"},
    {"proveedor":"andres","producto":"241","color":"VERDE"},
    {"proveedor":"pedro","producto":"243","color":"ROJO"}]
```

necesito que quede ordenado por el nombre del proveedor de la siguiente manera

```
array= ["proveedor":"andres","producto":"256","color":"AMARILLO"},
    {"proveedor":"andres","producto":"241","color":"VERDE"},
    {"proveedor":"juan","producto":"198","color":"BLANCO"},
    {"proveedor":"juan","producto":"244","color":"AMARILLO"},
    {"proveedor":"pedro","producto":"243","color":"ROJO"}]
```

Comment: Ya probaste con Array.sort()? que has intentado?

Comment: El método sort() ordena los elementos de un arreglo y devuelve el arreglo ordenado. Se le pasa un función de comparación. Si deseas ordenar de mayor a menor (<). Si deseas ordenar de menor a mayor (>). Para tu ejemplo sería: `console.log(array.sort(((a,b) => a.proveedor > b.proveedor)));`.

Answer (score 1):

intenta una matriz con $.each

```js
var array = [{"proveedor":"juan","producto":"198","color":"BLANCO"},
    {"proveedor":"andres","producto":"256","color":"AMARILLO"},
    {"proveedor":"juan","producto":"244","color":"AMARILLO"},
    {"proveedor":"andres","producto":"241","color":"VERDE"},
    {"proveedor":"pedro","producto":"243","color":"ROJO"}],
saveData = '';
$.each(array, function(i,d){
    $.each(array, function(i2,d2){
        if(d.proveedor.localeCompare(d2.proveedor) < 0){
            saveData = d2;
            array[i2] = d;
            array[i] = saveData;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Si quieres por numeros:

```js
var array = [{"proveedor":"juan","producto":"198","color":"BLANCO"},
    {"proveedor":"andres","producto":"256","color":"AMARILLO"},
    {"proveedor":"juan","producto":"244","color":"AMARILLO"},
    {"proveedor":"andres","producto":"241","color":"VERDE"},
    {"proveedor":"pedro","producto":"243","color":"ROJO"}],
saveData = '';
$.each(array, function(i,d){
    $.each(array, function(i2,d2){
        if(d.producto < d2.producto){
            saveData = d2;
            array[i2] = d;
            array[i] = saveData;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```